# How to force Savon to use a specific parameter case

Tags: ruby, web-services, soap, wsdl, savon

I"m trying to connect to a SOAP API using Savon.

The WSDL shows this:

```
wsdl:operation name="CustomerList" parameterOrder="Username Password Settings">
  <wsdl:input message="impl:CustomerListRequest" name="CustomerListRequest"/>
  <wsdl:output message="impl:CustomerListResponse" name="CustomerListResponse"/>
</wsdl:operation>
```

Customer Support says to use a request such as this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ei2="http://ei2.nobj.nable.com/">
  <soap:Header/>
  <soap:Body>
    <ei2:customerList>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <ei2:username>testaccount@n-able.com</ei2:username>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <ei2:password>!PDf2lfij23l!!</ei2:password>
    <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
    <ei2:settings>
      <!--Optional:-->
      <ei2:key>null</ei2:key>
      <!--Optional:-->
      <ei2:value>null</ei2:value>
     </ei2:settings>
  </ei2:customerList>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is my request:

```
{"SOAPAction"=>"\"CustomerList\"", "Content-Type"=>"text/xml;charset=UTF-8", "Content-Length"=>"452"}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:impl="http://www.n-able.com/mickey" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">  
   <env:Body>
     <impl:CustomerList>
      <username>test@test.com</username>
      <password>MytestPassword1234</password>
      <settings>
        <listSOs>false</listSOs>
      </settings>
    </impl:CustomerList>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

The difference is that the WSDL which Savon consumes and generates methods to call off of, is making my request send `CustomerList` instead of the `customerList` the API seems to be expecting.

Is there a way to force Savon to send `CustomerList` instead of `customerList` without constructing the entire SOAP Request by hand?

Edit 1
Found the answer in this Github Issue. https://github.com/savonrb/savon/issues/530

By adding the following to a gemspec, I was able to get a well formed request:

```
spec.add_runtime_dependency      'savon', '~> 2.3'
spec.add_runtime_dependency      'wasabi', '~> 3.2'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include one of those when you build your client:

```
convert_request_keys_to :camelcase  # or one of [:lower_camelcase, :upcase, :none]
```

or work without the WSDL and hand code the call with 'strings'.